# Are all constant maps homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider $f, g: X\to Y$ s.t. for all $x\in X$, $f(x) = p$ and $g(x) = q$, where $p, q\in Y$.

Are the maps necessarily homotopic?

If not, are there conditions under which they are homotopic--say, for example, I know that all maps in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homotopic

Comment: They are homotopic if and only if $p$ and $q$ can be connected by a path.

Comment: depends on arc-connected components

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments:

A homotopy from $f$ to $g$ is a continuous map $H: X \times I \to Y$ such that $H(x,0) = f(x) = p$ and $H(x,1) = g(x) = q$. Choose some $x_0 \in X$ and define $h: I \to Y$ by $h(t) = H(x_0,t)$, a notice that

- $h$ is continuous,
- $h(0) = p$,
- $h(1) = q$,

i.e. a path from $p$ to $q$ in $Y$.

In the other direction, given a path $h: I \to Y$ such that $h(0)=p$ and $h(1)=q$, we can define $H: X \times I \to Y$ by $H(x,t) = h(t)$ for all $x \in X$ and $t \in I$. This is a homotopy from constant maps $f$ to $g$.

Therefore...

**Proposition:** Constant maps $f,g: X \to Y$, with $f(x)=p$ and $g(x)=q$, are homotopic **if and only if** $p$ and $q$ are in the same path component of $Y$.